# Vanishing ratio of norms implies vanishing ratio of individual elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Consider two vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be parameterized by a value $t>0$, and suppose that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{|x(t)|}{|y(t)|}=0,$$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the standard Euclidean norm.  In other words as $t$ goes to zero the length of $x$ becomes insignificant relative to the norm of $y$.

I would like to claim then that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{|x_i(t)|}{|y_i(t)|}=0,$$

for any index $i \in 1, \ldots n$.  In other words, the vanishing of the ratio of norms implies the vanishing of the ratio of corresponding elements.

**BUT THIS STATEMENT IS FALSE -- SEE THE ANSWER BELOW!**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

It's not true.  Consider, for $n = 2$, $x(t) = [t^2, t^2]$, $y(t) = [t^3,t]$.  Then as $t \to 0$
$$\dfrac{\|x(t)\|}{\|y(t)\|} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2 t^4}}{\sqrt{t^6+t^2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2} t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} \to 0 $$ 
but
$$ \dfrac{x_1(t)}{y_1(t)} = \dfrac{t^2}{t^3} = \dfrac{1}{t} \ \text{diverges}$$

Comment: Thanks Robert -- nice example.  Guess I'll have to be more specific about the particular vectors $x$ and $y$ I'm considering (will post in a new question...).